# Can you dynamically add asyncPostBackTriggers to dynamically added textboxes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, triggers, postback

Hey everyone I'm using aspx in visual studios with c# code behind to generate textboxes on page load and add asynchronousPostBackTriggers to an update panel for those textboxes to trigger.

```
protected void PanelSans_OnLoad()
{
    SumBox sanPanel = new SumBox();
    sanPanel = (SumBox)ViewState["summaryBox"];
    TextBox[] boxes = new TextBox[sanPanel.getDNSCount()];
    Label[] labels = new Label[sanPanel.getDNSCount()];
    AsyncPostBackTrigger[] triggers = new AsyncPostBackTrigger[sanPanel.getDNSCount()];

    for(int i = 0; i < sanPanel.getDNSCount(); i++)
    {
        boxes[i] = new TextBox();
        boxes[i].Attributes["PlaceHolder"] = "Enter Additional Domains";
        boxes[i].ID = "SAN" + i;
        boxes[i].AutoPostBack = true;
        boxes[i].TextChanged += PanelSans_TextChanged;
        boxes[i].Attributes["runat"] = "server";

        labels[i] = new Label();
        labels[i].Attributes["Value"] = "Label" + i;

        triggers[i] = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
        triggers[i].ControlID = "SAN" + i;
        triggers[i].EventName = "TextChanged";
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < sanPanel.getDNSCount(); j++)
    {
        /*this.Controls.Add(boxes[j]);
        this.Controls.Add(labels[j]);*/
        PanelSans.Controls.Add(boxes[j]);
        PanelSans.Controls.Add(labels[j]);
        SanUpdate.Triggers.Add(triggers[j]);
    }
}
```

The method takes information previously made on the page and stored inside of a viewstate to determine how many boxes are created and how many triggers are made with those boxes. I've tried adding a text box hardcoded into the page along with a trigger for it in the update panel that works so I know the update panel works:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="SanUpdate" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
   <ContentTemplate>
      <div id="divSanPrice" style="font-size:24px;" class="orange" runat ="server"></div>
   </ContentTemplate>
   <Triggers>
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="sanPriceTest" EventName="TextChanged" />
   </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I've tried multiple tests such as hardcoding the trigger for one of the dynamically created the textboxes and all that did was stop the updatepanel from working all together.